# apache2 can't reinstall

Tags: server, 18.04, apache2, webserver

I am running the latest version of Ubuntu.

I continue to try and reinstall and delete Apache2 to fix my issue. The other day I was trying to run 2 websites on my server, and I must have screwed something up, so I have tried deleting all the files and reinstalling but nothing works.

```
info: Executing deferred 'a2enconf gitweb' for package gitweb
ERROR: Conf gitweb does not exist!
dpkg: error processing package apache2 (--configure):
installed apache2 package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 1
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.9) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-5) ...
Rules updated for profile 'Apache Full'
Rules updated for profile 'OpenSSH'

Errors were encountered while processing:
apache2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I continue getting:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
apache2
```

Please if someone could help I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sudo a2disconf gitweb
```

Otherwise you can try removing all the files associated with Apache:

```
sudo apt purge apache2*
sudo apt remove apache2*
```

Then install it again:

```
sudo tasksel
```

Comment: ERROR: Conf gitweb does not exist!

Comment: Try the later steps

Comment: sudo: tasksel: command not found

Comment: tried the middle two, still got same error